# Как происходит неявный вызов метода toString при создании экземпляра Java класса

Tags: java, ооп

Объясните, пожалуйста, на пальцах, каким образом вызывается метод `toString()` из класса `SubClass`. Ведь это не конструктор класса, нет явного вызова метода.

```
class Super{
    public String toString(){
        return "4";
    }
}
public class SubClass extends Super{
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString()+"3";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println( new SubClass() );
    }
}
```

Результат исполнения программы: 43

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А как насчет такого:

```
public class Super{
  public Super() {
  }
  public String toString(){
     return "4";
  }
}

public class SubClass extends Super{
  public SubClass() {
    super();
  }
  public String toString(){
     return super.toString()+"3";
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println( new SubClass() );
  }
}
```

Если посмотрите на имплементацию `println()` увидите следующее:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Еще чуть глубже, что же за статический метод `valueOf()` класса `String`:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Т.е. в конечном итоге `println()` вызывает метод `toString()` у `SubClass`, тот в свою очередь вызывает `toString()` у `Super`, получает 4, прикладывает к нему 3 и возвращает в `println()`

Java хороша тем, что вы всегда(почти) можете посмотреть на то, как работает тот или иной метод "не отходя от кассы" и как правило там никакой магии нет. 
Так что всегда когда что-то не понятно рекомендую смотреть имплементацию.